# How is "Encryption key SHA256" computed on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I [generated an AES key](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-encryption-keys#storage-generate-encryption-key-python) and used `gsutil` to upload a client-side encrypted file to GCP storage. The file is shown to be client-encrypted and the metadata contains an "Encryption key Sha256" that appears to be base 64.

When I calculate the `sha256sum` of my key string and convert to base 64, it does not match. How is this value computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash is computed on the base64 decoded key string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command:

```
export encryption_key=yxCPz7MD1bLjcBJXiXAlu6obBAAn2leIebkTtnxtB+U=
echo "${encryption_key}" | base64 -d |  openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | base64
```

Reference:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/how-can-i-get-a-base64-encoded-shax-on-the-cli?newreg=54d06c85faaf4d739723334c6f9e13d3